# Kotlin.math package not importing

Tags: import, kotlin

I'm trying to use kotlin.math.abs in a util.kt file, but the following code results in an "unused import" warning on the import statement and an unresolved reference where I use abs in the code.

```
import kotlin.math.abs

fun fuzzyEquals(a: Double, b:Double, epsilon: Double= 0.001) = abs(a-b) < epsilon
```

I'm using IntelliJ and gradle to organize the project. I'm on Intellij 2018.2.5 with Kotlin 1.3.0.

The folling code does work, so I don't think it's a problem with Kotlin as a whole

```
import kotlin.sequences.find

fun test() = listOf(1,2).find{it==1}
```

Comment: Does this code compile when you use gradle, e.g. when running `build` gradle task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions from `kotlin.math` package can be unresolved by one of the following reasons:

- you don't have the kotlin standard library in dependencies (it doesn't seem so from your question), or the version of that dependency is lower than that, where this package was introduced, namely 1.2. Check the `dependencies` block of your build file.
- `apiVersion` compiler option, which limits visible API to only available in the specified version, can be set. Check whether you have this option in Gradle build file and also check the effective version in the Kotlin facet of your module in IntelliJ project structure.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem entirely, but it got me going in the right direction! Thank you. 

Turns out my issue was that I depend on a package that has Kotlin 1.1 bundled in, and my build was defaulting to that instead of 1.3. Unlinking and relinking the project in Gradle seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Perhaps this has been accompanied with a warning "w: Some JAR files in the classpath have the Kotlin Runtime library bundled into them. This may cause difficult to debug problems if there's a different version of the Kotlin Runtime library in the classpath. Consider removing these libraries from the classpath"